# How can I pass the event.currentTarget.id inside $().css?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The purpose of this object is to display a popup if clicked on a div. Within the popup I want to display the css attributes from the div clicked. My question is how I would place the current.target.id event into this line `$("#container").css(this.css);` where it replaces #container so that i retrieve different values for each element I click on

Thanks in advance

```
    $(function () {
    function popup(){
        var self = this;
        this.identifier;
        this.popupStatus = 0;
        this.css = ["width", "height", "color", "background-color"];

            $("#container > *").on('click', ':not(#popup)', function (e) 
            {
                if(event.target.id!=='backgroundPopup')
                {
                    e.stopPropagation()
                    self.centerPopup();
                    self.loadPopup();
                    self.cssAttr(); 
                }
            });

            $("#backgroundPopup").click(function()
            {
                console.log('backgroundPopup');
                self.disablePopup();
            });     

            $(document).keypress(function(e)
            {
                if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1)
                {
                    self.disablePopup();
                }
            });

          this.cssAttr = function (e){

            var html = ["Adjust the settings:"];
            //problem
            var styleProps = $("#container").css(this.css);
            console.log(styleProps);

            $.each( styleProps, function( prop, value ) {
                html.push( prop + ": " + value );
            });

            $( "#result" ).html( html.join( "<br>" ) );
            }


          this.loadPopup = function (){
            if(this.popupStatus==0)
            {
                console.log('loadPopup');
                $("#backgroundPopup").css(
                {
                    "opacity": "0.7"
                });
                $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");

            this.popupStatus = 1;
            }
        }

        this.disablePopup = function (){
            if(this.popupStatus==1)
            {
                console.log('disablePopup');
                $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
                this.popupStatus = 0;
            }
        }

        this.centerPopup = function (){
            console.log('centerPopup');
            var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
            var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();

            $("#popupContact").css(
            {
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
                "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
            });

            $("#backgroundPopup").css(
            {
                "height": windowHeight
            });     
        }
    }
    var popup = new popup();
});
```

Comment: `$("#" + event.currentTarget.id)` ?

Comment: Why would you do that instead of `$(event.currentTarget)`?

Comment: when I do that, I get nothing

Comment: You aren't passing `event` to the function.

Comment: Yes I do, pass the event as 'e'

Comment: Yes, but then you are trying to access `event.target.id` – that does not correspond. It’s either naming the parameter `event` as well, or for just `e` then logically `e.target.id`.

Comment: Now I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined when I use console.log(e.currentTarget.id);

Comment: you have some mistakes. at `if(event.target.id!=='backgroundPopup')` you use `event` but you should use the parameter `e` of your callback. `event` is global variable that is not available  in all browsers. `this.cssAttr = function (e)` here you have a parameter `e` but you don't pass a parmeter when you call it here `self.cssAttr();`